# I want to know how I am reading (or writing) elements in an array wrong in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to draw pascal's triangle in C using a 2D array.

I think what is going wrong is something to do with how I am reading or writing to the array. When I look for a number in the (1st) for loop, what I'm doing seems to work but doesn't outside it?

I am coming at this after some coding in Python and am new to C

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void main()
{
    int n, i , j;
    int x[n][n];

    n = 4;
    for (j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
      for(i=0; i<n; i++)
      {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            x[0][j] = 1;
            printf("\n(%d, %d)", i,j);
        }
        if (i != 0)
        {
            x[i][j] = 0;
        }
        printf("%d", x[i][j]);
      }
    }

    printf("\n\n(x[0][0]) %d", x[0][0]);
    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      for(j = 0; j < (n); j++)
      {
        if (j == 0)
        {
            printf("\n%d    ", x[i][j]);
        }
        else
        {
            x[i][j] = x[i-1][j-1] + x[i][j-1];
            printf("%d  ", x[i ][j ]);
        }
      }
    }
    printf("\n");   
    return;
  }
```

any help would be very appreciated

Comment: `int n` --> `int n = 4`

Comment: it is correct @BLUEPIXY

Comment: @Ollie check my answer if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Correction:**
without assigning `n` a value
`x[n][n]` will not function
or try using dynamic allocation for using such runtime array.

I hope this is helpful. thanks

Comment: Thank you this was the main issue I think

Comment: I have accepted and upvoted it but the upvote cannot be seen as I don't have enough Karma yet

Comment: That's not an issue, My answer should be helpful that's something worthy to me :)

Answer (score 1):

One key issue I see in your second set of loops is the line that reads:

```
x[i][j] = x[i-1][j-1] + x[i][j-1];
```

You avoid this if j == 0, but not if i == 0.  For example when j == 1 but i == 0, you will try to access a position in the array at x[-1][0] which is outside of the memory allocated by your array.

I think in particular you want to change your second set of loops to something like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  for(j = 0; j < (n); j++)
  {
    if ((i == 0) || (j == 0))
    {
        printf("\n%d    ", x[i][j]);
    }
    else
    {
        x[i][j] = x[i-1][j-1] + x[i][j-1];
        printf("%d  ", x[i ][j ]);
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the inner if condition has been changed from if (j == 0) to if ((i == 0) || (j == 0)) to prevent indexing outside of your array bounds.

Comment: Thank you, this was an issue but the fix was't perfect as I was trying to print it out, the \n is only for when i == 0 so instead I put:

 for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
  printf("%d ", x[i][0]);
 }

before: for(j=0; j<n; j++)
and started it at j=1 instead

Comment: Interesting, when I came across your question someone had already edited your code to contain n = 4 before the first loop.  Both problems prevented your code from running without crashing; i.e. the accepted solution actually doesn't fix your problem by itself.  But I suppose you can only accept one answer.  Also, as far as the newlines go, I was merely suggesting a fix that prevented your program from crashing by indexing your array incorrectly rather than something that output your triangles the way you wanted to view them.

Comment: I did also find your post helpful, as it pointed out an issue with my code that I hadn't spotted. (I have upvoted it but it won't show you as I don't have enough karma) I thought that you were trying to give me a solution not pointing out a problem for me to fix. Your way is how I like to be taught as I can try do it myself.


I chose that answer as it explained the reason I needed to set n=4 before making the array as well as telling me that I had too.

Comment: No worries! After all, you can only choose one solution as the answer.  Glad to hear that together both fixes got your program working.